# writing mod-rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a htaccess file for the following URL to be parsed.

```
/folder/title-of-article/id=6
```

to be passed to-

```
/page.php?id=6
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your article title cannot contain slashes, You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/[^/]+/id=([0-9]+)$ /page.php?id=$1
```

This will match `/folder/<anything not containing slashes>/id=<digits>`

Comment: Yeah, there was a slash in the beginning of the rule, remove it and it will work. Sorry for the delay, i've been off for a few days.